# height of the link bootsrap menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Is it possible to change the height of the link selected inside of the bootstrap dropdown-menu? - see the area on the pic

```
      .collapse.navbar-collapse
        .nav.nav-pills.pull-left
          %li.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#"}
              Menu
              %span.caret
            %ul.dropdown-menu{:role => "menu"}
              %li= link_to 
              %li= link_to 
              %li= link_to
```

Comment: Just Check Is there any code on .navbar .nav > li > a{  padding:""; } example padding:15px 20px;

Comment: nice! also when I click on the dropdown toggle and not selecting anything, but click it back on, the shadow stays on?

Comment: it may be on Js loading or conflict I think

Comment: @Wazan can you suggest how to fix it? I am a bit new to JS

Comment: If you can give the online url I can check through firebug, without that I too cant surely say whare the ussue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.dropdown-menu a {
    padding: 3px 15px;
    line-height: 18px;

 }
```

OR

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is :) Add your own style, like:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a { line-height: 36px; }
```